# How do i import a class inside a loop and execute the function of the imported class

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Well, i am working on a discord bot and i am using TypeScript

Here's my event handler

```
readdirSync(resolve(__dirname, "..", "events")).forEach(async directory => {
        const evn = readdirSync(resolve(__dirname, "..", "events", directory)).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

        for (const file of evn) {
            const files = await import(resolve(__dirname, "..", "events", directory, file));
            if (files.eventName()) super.on(files.eventname(), (...args) => files.exec(...args));
            else continue;
        }
 });
```

And here's my EventRegistry class

```
import { Client } from "discord.js";

export default class EventRegistry {
    protected client: Client;
    public event: string;
    public constructor(client: Client, event: string) {
        this.client = client;
        this.event = event;
    } 

    public eventName(): string {
        return this.event;
    }
}
```

**Note:** All of my classes are default exported

So, the problem is when i try to import a class inside a for/of loop and execute the function of the class, it returns `TypeError: files.eventName is not a function`

How can i fix this?